# How to show the error from angular validator?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, validation, input

I have a Form. I want to check if the formControlName web is a isValidHttpUrl.

I have implemented a Custom Validator called web.validator.ts

How I can print a message above the input web if the web formControlName is not valid?

Part of company.component.ts file

```
initForm() {
    if(!this.empresaForm) {
      this.empresaForm = new FormGroup({
        email: new FormControl(''),
        name: new FormControl(''),
        phone: new FormControl(''),
        web: new FormControl('',[new WebValidator().validate])
      })  
    }
    else {
      this.editMode = true;
    }
  }
```

Part of company.component.html file

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
   <mat-label>Web</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="web" matInput placeholder="Pàgina web establiment" >
</mat-form-field>
```

Validator class:

```
import {  AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, Validator} from '@angular/forms';

export class WebValidator implements Validator {

  constructor() {
  }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    if(!control || !control.parent) return null;
    console.log(control.parent.get('web').value);
    if (isValidHttpUrl(control.parent.get("web").value)) {
        return null;
    }
    else return {
      'webNoOk': true
    };
  }
}

  function isValidHttpUrl(string) {
    let url;
  
    try {
      url = new URL(string);
    } catch (_) {
      return false;  
    }
  
    return url.protocol === "http:" || url.protocol === "https:";
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will display below input field.

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Web</mat-label>
  <input formControlName="web" matInput placeholder="Pàgina web establiment" >
  <mat-error *ngIf="empresaForm.get('web').errors?.webNoOk">Not valid url</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```